# Multiple select tags and bootstrap css grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to show several select tags in a row using Bootstrap CSS.
I have no problems making couple of inputs in a row. But if I change input tag to select, it shows only the first select. Here is a sample: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/183fws4t/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change

`<select class="form-control" />`

to

`<select class="form-control"></select>`

Example:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <select class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <select class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It work. I can you please explain why that makes different for select and not for input?

Comment: the input tag is a self closing tag or void element (like img, br, hr, link etc.) as for select it has a start and end tag `<select></select>`. You can read about it here http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements

Answer (score 0):

You simply need some `<option>` elements in your `<select>`. For example:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ckuijjer/1x8so5ms/